# Swift: Change image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have the following Swift code inside a function that splits an image in half vertically:

```
let myImage = imageView.image!

let newWidth = (myImage.size.width) / 2
let newHeight = myImage.size.height
var cropRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight)

var tempImage: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(myImage.CGImage!, cropRect)

let newImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: tempImage)!

println("Original Image: \(myImage.size)")
println("New Image: \(newImage.size)")

imageView.image! = newImage
```

The original `UIImage` is being displayed in a `UIImageView`, but I would like to display the new cropped `UIImage` in the `UIImageView` after I create it so that I can see what it looks like.

My last line of code `imageView.image! = newImage` did not work so I am trying to find a new solution.  I have looked through the documentation for `UIImageView` but there doesn't seem to be a straight forward method that changes the image.

Comment: for me that code totally works!

Comment: me too, I'd be inclined to think it's a problem with the image adjustment code first. But it's late and I'm too tired to grok it further.

Comment: This worked once I removed the unwrap (!) from `imageView.image`.  I'm not sure why, my understanding of Optionals is still vey basic.

Comment: my understand is：
imageView.image! = imageView.image! = newImage
1. imageView.image! reproduce a new var
2. then you assign newImage to the new var, so your imageView's property image is not set to newImage.